# JSP to compare the value from the input value

Tags: jsp

I have an use-case where I want to get the value from the input field and compare the value with the static string and have some forking around that.

For Eg:

```
<a:hiddenInput name="hiddenElement" value="0" id="hiddenElement" />
```

I have added the above hidden input element in the JSP page and have assigned value as `0` to it.

Now, in the same JSP, I need to compare `#hiddenElement` value with static number and have a if else condition, something like below

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test='%{#hiddenElement > 10}'>
        <tr>
           <td class="col-sm-3">
               <span>Hello World</span>
           </td>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I tried to search various resources but was not able find whether this can be possible or not.

Thanks in advance.